# SQL counting in table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've got a table that has a name, and a month in.

What would the SQL look like to make a table, that counts how many entries there is per month against each name. e.g.
[image]

Im confident to modify the vb.net code to reflect the actual needs of the project and to get it into a DGV, its just the SQL that i'm a bit iffy with, but this is the easiest way for me to explain what i'm trying to achieve.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Pete

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. You need to make your best attempt and then ask for help if it doesn't work. Also, what has SQL got to do with VB.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select name,
       sum(case when month(date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as month_1,
       sum(case when month(date) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as month_2,
       . . .
from t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified and worked like a charm, thanks chaps.

```
SELECT s_repair_location AS "Service Center",
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=01 then 1 else 0 end) AS Jan,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=02 then 1 else 0 end) AS Feb,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=03 then 1 else 0 end) AS Mar,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=04 then 1 else 0 end) AS Apr,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=05 then 1 else 0 end) AS May,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=06 then 1 else 0 end) AS Jun,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=07 then 1 else 0 end) AS Jul,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=08 then 1 else 0 end) AS Aug,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=09 then 1 else 0 end) AS Sep,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=10 then 1 else 0 end) AS Oct,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=11 then 1 else 0 end) AS Nov,
    Sum(case when month(s_entry_date)=12 then 1 else 0 end) AS "Dec"
FROM s_service_repairs
WHERE Year(s_entry_date) = 2019 and s_repair_location IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY s_repair_location
```